# append value to variable using sed - shell script

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, append

I am trying to search the file using the key and add 123 to the end of line. and other than the key "hello" I dont have values of hello. How can I achieve this sed or awk?

## file contents

hello="80,30,255,64"

## expected output

hello="80,30,255,64,123"

Comment: `trying to search the file using the key` you should add two sample lines, one with `hello` and other without... all answers so far have missed that point... and on SO you are expected to add the code you tried to solve

Answer (score 3):

try the below sed expression:

```
sed 's/"$/,123"/' inputfile
```

It should give you:

```
hello="80,30,255,64,123"
```

Answer (score 1):

using `awk`

```
awk 'sub(/"$/,",123&")+1' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ echo 'hello="80,30,255,64"' | awk 'sub(/"$/,",123&")+1'
hello="80,30,255,64,123"
```

`sub(/"$/,",123&")+1` is incase if `sub()`, does not return non zero, then still print such line

> ```
> I am trying to search the file using the key and add 123 to the end of line.
> ```

Can't find any key here, if you mean to say `hello` is your key then

```
awk '/^hello=/{ sub(/"$/,",123&") }1' infile > outfile
```

**Explanation:**

- `/^hello=/` - look for line starts with `hello=`

(`^` indicates the beginning of the string.)

- `sub(/"$/,",123&")` - substitute `"$`

( `$` indicates the end of the string )

with comma, 123 and `&`

( special character `&` appears in replacement, it stands for the precise substring that was matched by regexp. )

Answer (score 0):

Following awk code may help you in same.

```
awk -F"\"" '{$2=$2 ",123"} 1' OFS="\""  Input_file
```